# Defining nodes that do not have to be visited

Tags: or-tools

I'd like to define a routing problem using `RoutingModel` including nodes that are freed from the must-visit constraint, but have an influence on a capacity dimension if visited. Do you have any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **disjunction constraints** to make your nodes optional. You should add each node to its own disjunction group, each having a single element:

```py
    for node in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        routing.AddDisjunction(
            nodes=[node],
            penalty=1)
```

## Why does this work?

In a disjunction group, the solver will try to include in the solution exactly `max_cardinality` nodes from that group.

- If `penalty` is negative, this will be treated as a *hard constraint*, which means that the solver will not return a valid solution if the constraint is not satisfied.
- However, if `penalty` is positive, this will be a *soft constraint*, meaning that a violation will add a penalty to the global cost variable.

Therefore, in order to minimize the penalties, the solver will attempt to include in the solution as many nodes as possible, while still being allowed to leave some of them out.